# Online meeting using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: angular7, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on an `Angular 7` application that uses GraphAPI. I am trying to create an [online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta) from this application.

Each time I send a POST request I get 'Forbidden' as response. I have used apis's with Delegated permission before and it works.

Since online meeting requires 'Application Permission' I am not sure where to specify it. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the permissions in App Registration > your app > settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the way you are trying to access the token. I used to get the same error however, got resolved by passing userName and Password as well in the auth request and using grant_type as password.

[image]